# Image of composite fields is composite of images

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field, $L/K$ ad $F/K$ field (algebraic) extensions, and let $\sigma:FL \longrightarrow \overline{K}$ be a field homomorphism (so is injective), where $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$ and $FL$ is the composite of $F$ and $L$ (the smaller subfield of $\overline{K}$ that contains both $F$ and $L$). How can I prove that $\sigma(FL)=\sigma(F)\sigma(L)$?

This is what I did: since $F,L \subseteq FL$ we have that $\sigma(F),\sigma(L) \subseteq \sigma (FL)$, so this means that, for the minimality of $\sigma(F)\sigma(L)$, we have that $\sigma(F)\sigma(L) \subseteq\sigma(FL)$.

Is this correct? How can I do the other inclusion?

Comment: Notice that field homomorphisms are always injective. The zero map doesn't preserve the multiplicative identity and hence is not a homomorphism of fields.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg is injectiveness the key to show the other inclusion? Because I tried to wrap my head around it but it didn't go anywhere

Comment: No, but I wanted to explain why the remark "not the trivial one, so is injective" is not really adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows easily from the description via elements:
$$\textstyle F \cdot L = \{\sum_i a_i b_i : a_i \in F, \, b_i \in L\}$$
But you can also prove it with the definition as the smallest subfield that contains both fields:

You have already proved $\sigma(F) \sigma(L) \subseteq \sigma(FL)$. Conversely, observe that $E := \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(F)\sigma(L))$ is a subfield of $FL$, and that $F \subseteq \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(F)) \subseteq E$ and similarly $L \subseteq E$. Hence, $FL \subseteq E$. This means $\sigma(FL) \subseteq \sigma(F) \sigma(L)$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Since $\sigma$ is injective don't we have that $F=\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(F))$ and not just the $\subseteq$? And 2) are you saying that $E$ is a subfield of $FL$ because $\sigma(F)\sigma(L)\subseteq\sigma(FL) \Rightarrow E=\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(F)\sigma(L)) \subseteq\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(FL))=FL$? I know that these don't change anything, it's just for (my) clarity.

Comment: 1) Yes but this is not required for a proof. 2) No, I just use the following trivial lemma:

Let $\sigma : K \to L$ be a homomorphism of fields. Let $M \subseteq L$ be a subfield. Then $\sigma^{-1}(M) \subseteq K$ is a subfield.